# Is there way to define directional derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose: $M$ - manifold with boundary, $p\in\partial M$, $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function and $X\in T_pM$ is a tangent vector such that $X = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, and $X_n(p) < 0$.

How I should think about $X\cdot f$? Is there a way to define it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking whether or not $T_p M$ makes sense for $p \in \partial M$.

Comment: No, I am asking if $X\cdot f$ makes sense for $X\in T_pM$, where $p\in\partial M$ if $X_n(p) < 0$.